# getting a array object but cant access the elements inside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get all the posts of the people that are followed by the user, but Im getting an array of objects and I can't access the objects inside it. here is my code :

initialize the states:

```
const [following, setFollowing] = useState([]);
const [allPosts, setAllPosts] = useState([]);
```

create the collection reference and get the data, **this data is the Ids of the people the user follows** :

```
const followingColRef = collection(db, "users", uid, "following");

  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(followingColRef, (snapshot) => {
      setFollowing(
        snapshot.docs.map((item) => ({ ...item.data(), id: item.id }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
```

and then here im trying to get all the posts posted by every user id in the array created above (**following**):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const array = [];
    following.map((user) => {
      const postsColRef = collection(db, "users", user.id, "posts");

      onSnapshot(postsColRef, (snapshot) => {
        array.push(
          snapshot.docs.map((item) => ({ ...item.data(), id: item.id }))
        );
      });
    });
    setAllPosts(array);
  }, [following]);
  console.log(allPosts);
```

when I open the data logged into the console it would be something Like :

```
[
    [
        {
            "likes": 2,
            "user": "Some Name",
            "comments": 1,
            "body": "Somthing...",
            "uid": "cU1h2uh5CTMGKEKD4Wa986YUDqp1",
            "created_at": {
                "seconds": 1664450450,
                "nanoseconds": 779000000
            },
            "id": "Z7OcjSIY8OYKpbC1pdyq"
        }
    ]
]
```

but if I try and access `allposts[0]` I get undefined

so why is this happening and how can I remove the top layer array since it's not doing anything important

any help would be great thank

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `allPosts[0]` is undefined at the time you try to access it.

You can try two methods to achieve what you want

to remove the outer array you can try setting `allPosts` like this instead `setAllPosts(array[0])`

Then try a new `useEffect` like below to get around the returning undefined issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(allPosts[0])
}, [allPosts]);
```

Alternatively instead of everything above you can achieve removing the outer array and accessing the data in one go by doing this

```
useEffect(() => {
setAllPosts(prevPost => prevPost[0]);
console.log(allPosts[0])
}, [allPosts]);
```